# How to parse a string "{A,B,C}" into an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a variable like:

```
x = "{'A','B','C'}";
```

How do I convert it into an array of strings e.g `arr = ['A', 'B', 'C']`,
such that `arr[0] = 'A'` and so on. I know we can do regex parsing, but is there any simpler way ?

Comment: You could remove the first and last brackets,split by comma and parse the json at each element to get the final result. Assuming that the input always has that format exactly.

Comment: Can any of the single quoted strings include curlies or commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an excatct structue, the follwing will work:

```js
let x = "{'A','B','C','{E}'}";
let y = x.replace(/^\{/,'[').replace(/\}$/,']').replace(/'/g,'"');
let z = JSON.parse(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: What if one of the strings has a curly

Comment: @DanielA.White -  The answer is in case of a simple string like he have mentioned. using text parsing is always a source for problems. my answer is for similar and simple structure as I've mentioned. but, I've edited my example to support it.